# display p html tag on right top corner

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a p tag with count-names class on the right top corner. I do not want to use `margin-top: -20px`. Is there any other proper way to put it where I want to display?

Here is my code [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/yRNTy/1/)

html code

```
<p>First name: <input id="name" /></p>
<p>First name capitalized: <strong>NAME</strong></p>
<p class="count-names">1</p>​
```

css code

```
.count-names {
    float: right;
    top: 0;
}​
```

Comment: Instead of just a link, can you please add the relevant code to your questions? It makes the question useful to more people longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/yRNTy/2/

html :

```
<p>First name: <input id="name" /></p>
        <p>First name capitalized: <strong>NAME</strong></p>
<p class="count-names">1</p>
```

css :

```
.count-names {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    padding:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

**HTML:**

```
<p>First name: <input id="name" /></p>
<p>First name capitalized: <strong>NAME</strong></p>
<p class="count-names">1</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.count-names {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

`position: absolute` means position the element absolute to the document, independent of any other elements.

`top` and `right` are quite self-explanatory, they set the top and right position from the document.

Reference: [position - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position).

[See an example](http://jsfiddle.net/yRNTy/5/).

Here is the actual CSS I used in the example (just to make it look nice):

```
.count-names {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `p` tag before the rest of your code, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/yRNTy/3